# Expected value of a formula involving ordered random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value, order-statistics

I have three random real numbers from uniform distribution $[0,1]$, and also a constant $r\in [0,1]$. Supposed the three random numbers are sorted afterwards and denoted $a<b<c$.

I want to calculate the expected value of the following rule: if $r<a$, then result is $r+c-b-a$; if $a<r<c$, then result is $b+r-a-c$; if $r>c$, then result is $r+a-b-c$.

I have figured out the pdf of $a,b,c$, which is $3(1-p)^2,6p(1-p),3p^2$, and the expected values of those are $1/4,1/2,3/4$. However I cannot get the correct answer when putting these and different cases involving $r$.

Comment: "If $r<a$, the result is $r+d-b-c$"  -- what is $d$?

Comment: @uniquesolution I meant $c$, typo corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I cannot get the correct answer when putting these and different cases involving $r$.

Indeed, you cannot get the correct answer that way.   The variables are not independent.

The **joint** probability density function is: $\mathsf p_{a,b,c}(x,y,z)=3!~\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\lt y\lt z\leqslant 1}$

Use that.

Comment: Thanks. It's quite surprising when I realized the joint pdf is constant.

Comment: Indeed, but consider that there is no bias introduced by taking three independent samples of a uniform distribution and reordering them.  (Except for the edge cases where two or three values are equal.)